# How to dynamically disable/enable pages depending on certain variable?

Tags: 2010, workflow

I need to disable a page(and it's link, which is in left side navigation menu) when certain variable in a table in home page is equal to 3. How do I do this? Is it do-able through workflow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly the only way to do it it's only by javascript/jquery code.
You just have to find the correct link and hide it.

```
if($("tr:has(td:contains('3'))").length>0)
{
  $('a[href$="mypage.aspx"]').hide();
}
```